# If $\Phi$ is irreducible then $\Delta$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\Phi$ a root system with basis $\Delta$. Show that if $\Phi$ is irreducible then $\Delta$ is irreducible.

**Comments:** Suppose that $\Delta = \Delta_1 \cup \Delta_2$ is a partition of $\Delta$ into two non-empty mutually orthogonal subsets. I already showed a result that every root is conjugate to a simple root by an element of the Weyl
group $W$ which is generated by the simple reflections. Let $\Phi_1$ the set of
roots which are conjugate to an element of $\Delta_1$ and $\Phi_2$ the set those roots which are conjugate to an element of $\Delta_2$. We have $\Phi = \Phi_1 \cup \Phi_2$.

I need to show that $(\Phi_1,\Phi_2) = 0$ to conclude that $\Phi$ is irreducible and get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\beta\in\Phi_1$, and $\beta=w(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in\Delta_1$, $w\in W$. Now $w$ is a product of simple reflections, and the action of a simple reflection $s_i$ corresponding to a simple root $\alpha_i$ in $\Delta_1$ adds a multiple of $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha$, (or whatever root it is after applying some other previous simple reflections in a decomposition of $w$), but the simple reflections for simple roots in $\Delta_2$ leave it unchanged, since $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are orthogonal. So $\beta$ is in the span of $\Delta_1$. Likewise, if $\gamma\in\Phi_2$, then $\gamma$ is in the span of $\Delta_2$. Thus $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are orthogonal since $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are orthogonal.

Comment: I could not understand why the action of a simple reflection $s_i$ corresponds to a simple root $\alpha_i \in \Delta_1$. Why  belongs to $\Delta_1$?

Comment: What I have is the following: if $\alpha \in \Phi_1$ then exists $w \in W$ such that $w\alpha \in \Delta_1$, ie, $s_1s_2 ... s_t(\alpha) \in \Delta_1$. How to conclude that $\alpha \in span{\Delta_1}$?

Comment: @Croos Then $\alpha=w^{-1}(\beta)$ for some $\beta\in\Delta_1$, and $w^{-1}=s_t\cdots s_1$. Then writing $\alpha_i$ for the simple root for $s_i$,  $s_1(\beta)=\beta-\frac{2(\alpha_1,\beta)}{(\alpha_1,\alpha_1)}\alpha_1$. So if $\alpha_1\in\Delta_1$, the resulting root $s_1(\beta)$ is a linear combination of $\beta$ and $\alpha_1$, hence in the span of $\Delta_1$. If $\alpha_1\in\Delta_2$, $(\beta,\alpha_1)=0$, so $s_1(\beta)=\beta$, hence still in the span of $\Delta_1$. Now repeat the argument inductively to see $\alpha$ is in the span of $\Delta_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is observe that $W\cong W_1\times W_2$ where $W_i=\langle s_\alpha\mid \alpha\in \Delta_i\rangle$ ($i=1,2$). In this case, $W_1$ is the stabilizer of $\Phi_2$, $W_2$ is the stabilizer of $\Phi_1$, and we have $\Phi_1=W_1\Delta_1$ and $\Phi_2=W_2\Delta_2$. It now follows that if $\beta\in\Phi_i$ ($i=1,2$), then 
$$\beta=\sum_{\alpha\in \Delta_i}c_\alpha \alpha$$
for some $c_\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. It is now straightforward to conclude that $\Phi_1\perp\Phi_2$.